# How can I change a http header dynamically in react-admin?

Tags: http, http-headers, react-admin, api-platform.com

Not important, but: I use the react-admin w/ Symfony (Api platform) backend. The documentation is [here](https://api-platform.com/docs/admin/). The authentication doc is [here](https://api-platform.com/docs/admin/authentication-support/).

Yes, I know, I can add custom header to the dataProvider like this

```
let locale = 'en_GB';

const entrypoint = document.getElementById('api-entrypoint').innerText;

const fetchHydra = (url, options = {}) => baseFetchHydra(url, {
    ...options,
    headers: new Headers({
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.getItem('auth')}`,
        'X-LOCALE': locale, // <----- THIS IS THE POINT - I WOULD LIKE
                                      TO CHANGE THIS HEADER LATER, W/O RELOAD THE PAGE
    }),
});

const apiDocumentationParser = entrypoint => ....more code

const dataProvider = baseHydraDataProvider(entrypoint, fetchHydra, apiDocumentationParser);

ReactDOM.render(
    <HydraAdmin
        dataProvider={dataProvider}
        ....more code>
        ....more code
    </HydraAdmin>,
    document.getElementById('api-platform-admin')
);
```

**How can I change the `X-LOCALE` http header permanently what can be used by every http request?** Of course it would be the best if I did not need to change every component and every request.

I need a changeable http header globally, because in the backend, I use Doctrine Extensions bundle's [Translatable](https://symfony.com/doc/1.2/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html). So, it can return the proper translations by `X-LOCALE` header.

**EDIT:**

I found a solution but it is not too good... I put the locale variable to the localStorage, and after that I reload the page:

```
...more code

if (null === localStorage.getItem('locale')) {
    localStorage.setItem('locale', 'en_GB');
}

const entrypoint = document.getElementById('api-entrypoint').innerText;

const fetchHeaders = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.getItem('auth')}`,
    'X-LOCALE': localStorage.getItem('locale'),
};

...more code
```

I created a Select field in appBar:

```
...more code

    const handleChangeLocale = (event) => {
        localStorage.setItem('locale', event.target.value);
        window.location.reload();
    };

    return (
        <AppBar {...props} className={classes.appbar}>
            ...more code
            
            <Select
                value={localStorage.getItem('locale')}
                onChange={handleChangeLocale}>
                <MenuItem value={"en_US"}>English, US</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={"en_GB"}>English, GB</MenuItem>
            </Select>
        </AppBar>
    );
```

It is an ugly solution, I figured out. But I could not find any better solution that related to the official documentation. Obviously I tried w/ my best friends: Google, Qwant, Duckduckgo.